# Как программно получить рута?

Tags: c++, qt, mac

При запуске программы из терминала после получения прав рута (su...) все необходимые действия программа выполняет нормально. При запуске от пользователя administrator:admin, программа запрашивает права диалогом, выполняет почти всё, кроме одной операции. Функция SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent(...) возвращает ошибку "write permissions error". При этом не важно, что ввести в диалог авторизации administrator+пароль или root+пароль.

Как лечить, что делать?

Comment: видимо, вы когда запустили от рута, записали файл и теперь, чтобы его перезаписать нужны права рута. нужна ли защита этого файла от записи? может chown user?

Comment: Думаю не в файле дело, вроде нет таких. Данную задачу решил запуском скрипта, у которого установлен флаг SUID. Скрипт запускает вторую копию основной программы, но она уже получает права рута и выполняет все необходимые действия.

Comment: @pier_nasos Можете добавить ваш комментарий с решением как овтет к этому вопросу, а потом его принять? За это плюшки полагаются :)

Comment: Оформил как ответ. Не нашел, как принять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу решил запуском скрипта, у которого установлен флаг SUID. Скрипт запускает вторую копию основной программы с разными параметрами, и она уже получает права рута и выполняет все необходимые действия.

Comment: Скрипт? Или бинарник?

Comment: Программа (бинарник) запускает скрипт (sh), который запускает эту же программу.

Comment: Для скриптов SUID-бит не работает